# Website works fine with http but not with the https #laravel

Tags: html, http, https, server

I am trying to figure out that why my sub domain website works fine with **Http** but not when its **https**.
Is there SSL certification problem.

[image]

Comment: Check your developer tools console (press F12) for errors regarding HTTP/HTTPS errors

Comment: yes it shows I am trying to access a non-secure http//{path} on https loaded page, so I guess changing HTTP to HTTPS will work fine?

Comment: Yes that should be it, but these other servers need to support HTTPS as well.

Comment: thanx :)   issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers given till now are correct but none solved my problem.

The main problem was my application was behind CloudFlare

Laravel detects a Request as secure or insecure by checking a HTTP header i.e.

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']

which remains HTTP even the Request is HTTPS due to cloudflare.

CloudFlare sets a different header for the same i.e.

> $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']

Which must be checked to detect a request is secure or not

Following this article and making some changes to this I successfully managed to generate HTTPS URL without making any changes to previous application code.

Credit Cybersupernova (Stack User )

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of scripts that are linking with `http`. Browsers won't run these on a secure page. You need to change the links to `https`:

```
<script src="http://bloodsuvidha.vampy.in/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is also true with stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bloodsuvidha.vampy.in/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanx :) i appreciate your answer

Comment: I am on a laravel project, i use "url('path')"  which automatically creates the url path. It doesnt worked for me

Comment: I don't know anything about laravel. You should mark this answer as correct for this question and ask a different one about the laravel problem.